# Date from $n$-th day of the year?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm currently working with basic trig. functions. The task often defines a function $f(x)$ where $x$ is the day of the year. Then they ask what date something occurs, but the math only outputs the $x$-th day of the year.

I was wondering if there is a simple function/script out there that does this? Leap years not taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple script for this, because the month lengths are so irregular. Your best bet is something like a 'switch' case, here is some pseudo code. I assume $x$ starts at 0.

```
switch (x)
if between 0 and 30:
    return January, x + 1
if between 31 and 58:
    return February, x - 30
```

etcetera.

Note that most programming languages have date libraries which can do this for you, e.g. Java with a Calendar setting the [`DAY_OF_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) component.